# Getting count of records that are partitioned using partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having difficulties in setting up this query and getting the desired results. I want to partition by SSN and get a count of the number of officers a borrower has used.

This is the how far I have gotten so far

```
USE byte 
GO
-- This creates a temporary table that you can reference for other queries
;WITH cteDupes AS 
(
-- find all rows that have the same MobilePhone. 
-- we consider those rows are duplicates so we partition on them
-- Order the partitioned group by most populated field, then by latest funding date
    SELECT  DENSE_RANK() OVER(Order By a.ssn) as ranked,
            /*ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone ORDER BY DateModified)      AS RNA,*/
            b.LoanOfficerUserName, a.SSN, concat(a.FirstName, ' ', a.LastName) as 'Borrower Name', a.homephone,
a.email, c.fundingdate
    FROM borrower a
    join byte.dbo.filedata b
on a.filedataid=b.filedataid
join byte.dbo.status c
on a.filedataid=c.filedataid
join byte.dbo.organization d
on b.organizationid=d.organizationid
where
d.code not in ('260%') and a.SSN not in ('null', '') and a.SSN not like '0000000%'
)
--Dedupe data and place it into a new table created
select * into  contactdedupe.dbo.borrowerownership1
from cteDupes
```

This give me a list of all borrowers partitioned by SSN and the rnd which basically is like 1,2,3 then 1,2,3,4 denotes to seperate groups. How can i display this as a count of borrowers to loan officers. 
Thanks, i tried to use a pivot table with no luck either

One major point is that I dont want to display SSN field in the report

Comment: Add desired output info.

Comment: Looking for something like this..
Group A  (this is grouped by SSN)       count(loanofficerusername)
---Borrower Name
---Loan Officer user name                       (n)

Comment: your question and query are confusing.. it would be better if you showed an example of your table structure and what result you want.  it almost sounds like you just want to use `COUNT(LoanOfficerUserName) OVER (Partition By SSN)`

Comment: I have no idea what you're looking for and what hurdles you've encountered.

Comment: Sorry.. COUNT(LoanOfficerUserName) OVER (Partition By SSN) is what a i need but how do i group it so it shows the loanofficer usernames underneath. I can do this in a pivot table on excel but I have to place the SSN field in the report. And I dont want to do that. I hope that makes sense

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145240/assigning-a-row-number-in-sql-server-but-grouped-on-a-value

Answer (score 0):

[Assigning a Row Number in SQL Server, but grouped on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145240/assigning-a-row-number-in-sql-server-but-grouped-on-a-value)
This is what I was looking for, once I was able to assign a 'group number' I was able to then use a pivot table in excel and get the desired results. Thank you all for your assistance